# Meta icon is wrong in app

Tags: bug, status-norepro, ios-app, favicon

Observe the site icon from the sidebar:

> [image: sidebar]

...but if you thought that was an old icon, wait until you see it in the app feed!

> [image: feed]

Comment: This seems to be specific to the iOS version; the Android version of the app doesn't have this problem. Just throwing a data point out there.

Comment: The old MSE logo is still being returned via the API, and I'm still able to get it in the Android app. The featured meta post is because that post is showing in the Stack Overflow "Featured on meta" sidebar box.

Comment: @StevenV sure, but it's showing in the sidebar for *all* sites. It isn't specific to SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was an old API issue when the Meta Stack Overflow -> Meta Stack Exchange split took place. The issue is no longer happening.